# Using vanilla javascript, add class to body from within head

Tags: javascript

I want to do a quick javascript check from within the `head` tag, like so:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <script>
            document.body.classList.remove("no-js");
            document.body.classList.add("js");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class='no-js'>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

This doesn't work. `Cannot read property classList of null`, which...fair enough. If I move the `<script>` tag into `<body>`, everything works, but I want the `<script>` tag in `<head>`.

What are my options?

EDIT: I should have been much clearer about the error. I realize the problem is that body hasn't loaded when I'm trying to to add the class. However, I was using a bit of Modernizr originally and it was somehow able to modify the body class from within the head and I don't *think* it was using `window.onload` or anything like that.

Comment: code is running before body is loading

Comment: Yeah, I know. That's what the error means.

Answer (score 11):

Run the code after body is loaded. There are several approaches to solve the problem:

1. Move the code into a named function defined in global context and call it in `onload`.

```html
<html>

<head>
  ...
  <script>
    function load() {
      document.body.classList.remove("no-js");
      document.body.classList.add("js");
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="load();" class='no-js'>
  ...
</body>

</html>
```

2. Or move code to [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event listener callback in order to call after dom elements are loaded.

```html
<html>

<head>
  ...
  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      document.body.classList.remove("no-js");
      document.body.classList.add("js");
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body class='no-js'>
  ...
</body>

</html>
```

3. Or move the entire `script` tag to the end of the page.

```html
<html>

<head>
  ...
</head>

<body class='no-js'>
  ...
  <script>
    document.body.classList.remove("no-js");
    document.body.classList.add("js");
  </script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: @Eoin Look closer; these are definitely three different solutions.

Answer (score 1):

At the time the javascript is executed there is no body tag, because the browser hasn't gotten around to it yet. You need to either add the script tag in the body, or add it as an event to execute when the document has loaded. See [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) for an example.